# How to get clicked coordinates on the line in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers, we get the line feature on the clicked point by such kind of codes:

```
      map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
        var hit = false;
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function() {
          hit = true;
        }, {
          hitTolerance: hitTolerance
        });
        if (hit) {
          style.getStroke().setColor('green');
          statusElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;A feature got hit!';
        } else {
          style.getStroke().setColor('black');
          statusElement.innerHTML = '&nbsp;No feature got hit.';
        }
        feature.changed();
      });
```

But, with this, we can't get exact point coordinates on the line, because of `hitTolerance` setting's effect.
How to get nearest point coordinates on the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
    var hit = false;
    var point;
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature) {
      hit = true;
      point = feature.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(e.coordinate);
    }, {
      hitTolerance: hitTolerance
    });
```